# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in SignalR asp.net MVC identity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, asp.net-identity, signalr-hub

this is the code of my hub class

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
  { 
    [Authorize]

    public void Send(string name, string message )
    {

        string uid = Context.Request.User.Identity.GetUserName();
        Debug.WriteLine(uid);

       // Debug.WriteLine();

        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(uid, message);
    }
 }
```

when executed this line  string uid = Context.Request.User.Identity.GetUserName();
its give me this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
I cannot get the username of logged in user . How can I  get login user information from connectionId or anything else ?

Comment: What kind of logging method you use ? (forms, AD)

Comment: asp.net identity I am using for authentication

Comment: Could you check which object is empty (null) ? Is it request, or user, or maybe identity ?

Comment: how can I check this object is empty or not ? If user is authenticate ?

Comment: Paste a breakpoint at this line (I'm assuming that you using Visual Studio) string uid = Context.Request.User.Identity.GetUserName();

and than place cursor over each object.

Comment: Yes I am using visual studio. I already used  those step but its give me  null ....But I did not understand why I am getting null

Comment: If your context is null make sure that you mapping signalR, as @Quentin wrote bellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your startup check if you are mapping signalR after configuring authentication :

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
  var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true };
  ConfigureAuth(app);
  app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);

}
```

Comment: var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true };
  ConfigureAuth(app);
this line what is doing here ?

Comment: With `EnableDetailedErrors` you will get the full error stack in your browser console.